# Any way to use 'clear' in a Bash script *without* its byte sequence being output to stdout?

Tags: bash

So say I want to use the `clear` command in a script that will be used to generate output ('data') to be piped or redirected to a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "data"
```

This pollutes `stdout` like so:

```
<U+0018>[H<U+0018>[2J[3Jdata
```

If I try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear 1>/dev/null
echo "data"
```

The offending byte sequence is redirected to `/dev/null`, but then `clear` also doesn't have any effect on the terminal.

Is there any way to effectively use `clear` in a script without generating junk output?

Comment: Have you checked to set a term temporarily where clear does not work by sending control characters (what you call "junk")? Not sure if such a thing exists, though...

Comment: Would doing `if [ -t 1 ] ; then clear; fi;` work for you? Only run the clear command if the current output is attached to a terminal, and skipping it if the output of the script is redirected to a file

Comment: @Ferrybig this solution will work for me. Thank you!

Comment: Another option: `clear >$(tty)`

Comment: @Alireza also good to know. Appreciated!

Comment: Why use `clear` to begin with? All it does is output `$LINES` number of `'\n'` to the terminal. (scroll back and check) If you are worried about the leftowvers, just clear manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution you could do, is detecting if the `STDOUT` (1) is connected to a terminal. This comes from the perspective that you either redirect to a file, or output to a terminal, but neither at the same time (as can be done with `tee`)

Your clear command then becomes:

```
if [ -t 1 ] ; then clear; fi
```